# Can't open moved mails on thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

If I move an email from the inbox to a local folder, and then I look for it with the thunderbird search engine I can find it, but when I want to open it this one seems to be empty.
[image]
This is when a try to open a mail called "Configuración de pentaho"

I found it but it seems empty.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple acctually:

First shut down thunderbird

go to thunderbird config folder:

```
 cd ~/.thunderbird/
```

open you profile folder:

```
~/.thunderbird  ls
88qcri7r.default  appreg  Crash Reports  profiles.ini
cd 88qcri7r.default
```

and remove the `global-messages-db.sqlite`

then restart thunderbird and start checking the status of the indexing in on `Tools>Activity Manager`

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/rebuilding-global-database